# Accessing a class/method from a DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a CPP DLL that I've compiled and I'm trying to access a particular function within it in C#

Here is the code in my DLL

base.cpp:
https://paste.privatecode.net/view/c513ec8f

base.hpp
https://paste.privatecode.net/view/afb871d7

Here's the code where I'm attempting to access the method from the DLL in C#:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        [DllImport("meshLib.dll")]
        static extern string getType(FileStream file);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    getType(fs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is I'm getting an error saying it cannot find an entry point for `getType`, and I'm not sure how to access it as it's being accessed via the `base` class in the CPP header file (base.hpp). Can anyone shed some light on how I would access this `getType` function?

Any pointing in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/use-c-codes-in-a-c-project-wrapping-native-c-with-a-managed-clr-wrapper/

Comment: Zac, check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.entrypointnotfoundexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: let me know if that helps